# changing the input while using native module

Tags: javascript, ios, reactjs, react-native, healthkit

In my App i am am using React Native's Native Modules to execute healthkit functionalities.
Healthkit query is written in the swift file. In the front-end i call all the methods i defined in the swift file.

Healthkit.js file:

```
import { NativeModules } from 'react-native';

const { MyHealthLibrary } = NativeModules;

export default MyHealthLibrary as any;
```

App.js:

```
import MyHealthLibrary from './Healthkit.js';


executeQuery = () => {
let obj = {
        read: [
          "HKQuantityTypeIdentifierHeartRate"
        ],
        write: [
          "HKQuantityTypeIdentifierHeartRate"
        ]
      }

MyHealthLibrary.requestAuthorization(obj)

}
```

I get the below screen. This works perfectly fine.

[image]

**Now i want to do something like below.**
Here instead of sending "**HKQuantityTypeIdentifierHeartRate**" i want to send just "HearRate" and in the Healthkit.js file i want to assign the real variable. But i am just not able to do this.

Healthkit.js file:

```
import { NativeModules } from 'react-native';

const { MyHealthLibrary } = NativeModules;
 const Read = {
    HeartRate: "HKQuantityTypeIdentifierHeartRate"
  }

  const Write = {
    HeartRate: "HKQuantityTypeIdentifierHeartRate"
  }


let HealthKit = Object.assign({}, MyHealthLibrary, {
    Constants: {
        Read: Read,
        Write: Write
    }
});


export default Healthkit as any;
```

App.js:

```
import Healthkit from './Healthkit.js';

executeQuery = () => {
let obj = {
        read: [
          "HeartRate"
        ],
        write: [
          "HeartRate"
        ]
      }

Healthkit.requestAuthorization(obj)

}
```

How can i achieve this?? Any suggestions would be great!!

Answer (score 0):

I think, in this way we can achieve it!

Healthkit.js file:

```
import { NativeModules } from 'react-native';
const { MyHealthLibrary } = NativeModules;

export const permissions = {
    HeartRate: "HKQuantityTypeIdentifierHeartRate"
}

export default MyHealthLibrary as any;
```

App.js:

```
import MyHealthLibrary, { permissions } from './Healthkit.js';

executeQuery = () => {
    const { HeartRate } = permissions;
    const grantedPermissions = {
        read: [HeartRate],
        write: [HeartRate]
    };
    MyHealthLibrary.requestAuthorization(grantedPermissions);
}
```